# C# How to randomly generate string depending on what user has chosen using databinding

Tags: c#, dictionary, data-binding, combobox

I'm working in C# and I've been given these criteria to meet:

   Implement a GUI (Windows Form Application) Horoscope application with the following  functionality:

   Hint: Use collections to Bound data at Run time.

   A combo-box displaying all the signs

   An image control to be updated with the selected sign

   A list-box with all the predictions for the selected sign

   UI to add a prediction for a given sign and refresh the list

I was able to get the combobox to populate with the signs I've chosen doing this:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable Horoscope = new DataTable();
    DataColumn dc1 = new DataColumn("Sign");
    // DataColumn dc2 = new DataColumn("Reading");

    Horoscope.Columns.Add(dc1);
    // Horoscope.Columns.Add(dc2);

    Horoscope.Rows.Add("Libra");
    Horoscope.Rows.Add("Leo");
    Horoscope.Rows.Add("Virgo");
    Horoscope.Rows.Add("Scorpio");

    cmbHoro.DataSource = Horoscope;
    cmbHoro.DisplayMember = "Sign";
}
```

My question is how can I assign lets say 3 different readings to each sign then depending on the user picking a sign in the combo box one of the three readings is shown?

Comment: **Hint: Use collections to Bound data at Run time** this is your answer. First, you need to define a data structures for this task eg. Signs, Readings,etc will be entity. They you can map them to display your data based in user selection.

Comment: using DataTable is must? or you can do it with other data structure ?

Answer (score 0):

you have used `DataTable` in question, I am using `Dictionary` here in answer.
you can use `DataTable` too, then you need to make columns and relationship accordingly. 
Main motive of this answer is to show you how you can dynamically change entries of `listbox` on selection of `combobox`

here we have a class which holds Horoscope related data : `HoroscopeData`

```
public class HoroscopeData
{
    public string sign;
    public List<string> prediction;

    public HoroscopeData(string sign)
    {
        this.sign = sign;
        this.prediction = GetPredictionForSign(sign);
    }

    private List<string> GetPredictionForSign(string sign)
    {
        List<string> predition = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            predition.Add("Prediction of " + sign + " " + i.ToString());

        return predition;
    }
}
```

and our data structure is

`public Dictionary<int, HoroscopeData> Horoscope = new Dictionary<int, HoroscopeData>();`

so our code will look like,

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Dictionary<int, HoroscopeData> Horoscope = new Dictionary<int, HoroscopeData>();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Horoscope.Add(1, new HoroscopeData("Aris"));
        Horoscope.Add(2, new HoroscopeData("Libra"));
        Horoscope.Add(3, new HoroscopeData("Leo"));

        //adding items in combobox, with tag which is associated with our main data
        //  so we can easily fetch prediction out of it whenever selection changes
        foreach(int tag in Horoscope.Keys)
        {
            CmbItem item = new CmbItem(Horoscope[tag].sign, tag);
            comboBox1.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //here on combobox selection, we are fetching predictions of selected sign
        // and add them in listbox
        CmbItem selectedItem = (CmbItem)(((ComboBox)sender).SelectedItem);
        List<string> predictions = Horoscope[selectedItem.tag].prediction;

        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        foreach (string pre in predictions)
            listBox1.Items.Add(pre);
    }
}
```